# Echo a Ruby script result into a Bash script variable

Tags: bash, wget

I have written a small Ruby script that outputs a user chosen URL. I would like to nest this URL into my Bash script so that it feeds directly into the wget portion rather than forcing the user to copy and paste the link. The current code is as follows:

```
>echo "Choose file to download"  
>./myscript.rb #  
>echo "Copy and Paste URL"  
>read answer  
>wget -O /myfile.zip "$answer"
```

Any help on making this would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
>"Choose file to download"
>18 obfuscated1.zip 891 Thu, 18 Apr 2013 16:13:05 GMT
>19 obfuscated2.zip 892 Fri, 19 Apr 2013 16:13:53 GMT
>20 obfuscated3.zip 893 Sat, 20 Apr 2013 16:13:16 GMT
>20
>http://s3-us.amazonaws.com/obfuscated3.zip/AWSAccessKeyId=/Expires=/Signature=
```

URL is tokenized in output and abbreviated here for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using command substitution:

```
answer=$(./myscript.rb)
wget -O /myfile.zip "$answer"
```

**Update:**

I haven't considered your script produces output other than the URL you are interested in.

Given that you can, at least:

1. modify `myscript.rb` to emit the URL on the standard output and the other messages on the standard error. Then you should be able to use the solution above.
2. run `wget` inside `myscript.rb` using the [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) Ruby method like this:

   ```
   # the url variable holds the URL chosen by the user
   system("wget -O /myfile.zip #{url}")
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Using that command froze the script at "answer=$(./myscript.rb)". I think because the user feeds an answer inside the Ruby script, which produces the appropriate URL. Is there a way I can echo the URL result into the variable or do you think it best to look for a Ruby solution?

Comment: It shouldn't freeze. Try replacing your `myscript.rb` with this super simple Ruby script `puts(gets.chomp)`. It freezes?

Comment: It didn't freeze; `myscript.rb` is probably prompting the user to enter something, but the prompt is not displayed because it is captured by the `$(...)` syntax.

Comment: @chepner it's quite a point, I just didn't consider that... @LFoos24 Can you post a sample output from `myscript.rb`?